# Searching dictionary keys using split

Tags: python, dictionary, split

I'm making a Book Management Program, and I want to search books.
I made a simple program, but I want to use '.split()' to make my Book Management Program.

For example, if one book's title is 'python book', I can type 'python' or 'book' to find the title. But we don't have to type 'thon' to find the title. If there are two books ('Python book' , 'Java book') and I type 'book' to find the title, it shows me all the books that have 'book' in title.

The dictionary format is:

```
Book_dic[Title] = [ISBN, author, company, price]
```

My program:

```
elif num == 2:
    print("Enter the book you want to search.")
    book_search = input("1. Title : ")

    for i in sorted(Book_dic):
        if book_search in i:
          print(i,Book_dic[i][0],Book_dic[i][1],Book_dic[i][2],Book_dic[i][3])                
    print('\n')
```

Comment: You already are looping over all the keys. Have you tried splitting that key yet?

Comment: No i didnt tried

Comment: So try it out. `i` is one of the keys (a title). Split it and see if `book_search` is in the resulting list.